# Хочу вывести результаты рейтинга конкретных пользователей плагин (kk Star Ratings)

Tags: php, wordpress

Установил плагин (kk Star Ratings) для wordpress. Никак не получается выводить рейтинг конкретных пользователей.

`<?php 
if(function_exists("kk_star_ratings_get")) 
{ 
$top_rated_posts = kk_star_ratings_get($total); 
} 
?>`

Нужно вывести суммарный рейтинг пользователя за посты которых проголосовали. А голосовалка есть под каждым постом.

Comment: что-то подсказывает, что в функцию kk_star_ratings_get() нужно передавать id записи/пользователя. Что у вас в переменной $total?

Comment: В переменной $total  лимитированный (int)

Comment: есть такая подсказка:
$top_rated_posts will contain an array of objects, each containing an ID and ratings. 
Example Usage:

`foreach($top_rated_posts as $post)
{
 // you get $post->ID and $post->ratings
 // Do anything with it like get_post($post->ID)
 // ...
}`

Comment: сделал так:
`<?php 
if(function_exists("kk_star_ratings_get")) 
{ 
$top_rated_posts = kk_star_ratings_get($post->ID); 
} 
?>`

теперь `$top_rated_posts` выводит массив что-то типа:

`Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 48 [post_title] => Ответ на вопрос: 'Не санкционированные радары' (id: 4080) [ratings] => 5.00 )  итд рейтинги)`